# Getting the amount of users with certain role who reacted to a message with a certain emoji

Tags: discord.js

So I am writing a discord bot for me and my friends. And I encountered this problem: I need to find the number of people that voted by reacting, but I need to count only people authorized to vote (having role gives authorization).
I tried to use:

```
const result = await voting.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 15000 });
console.log(result.get('').count);
```

But that returns the total number of people that voted no matter the filter that I made
I tried Reaction Collector but I couldn't get it to work.
Please, help!

Comment: What filters have you tried?

Comment: @Aplet123 I tried `const filter = (reaction, user) => (reaction.emoji.name === ''||reaction.emoji.name === '')&&(message.member.guild.members.cache.find(r=> r.id == user.id).roles.cache.has(grarole.id)==true||message.member.guild.members.cache.find(r=> r.id == user.id).roles.cache.has(botrole.id)==true);`
Where grarole is the one that gives authorization and botrole is one that bot has.
I used second one to ensure there always is emoji.

Comment: Try this:
``const filter = (reaction, user) => {
 if(reaction.emoji.name !== '' && reaction.emoji.name !== '') return false;
 let member = message.guild.members.cache.find(r => r.user.id === user.id);
    return member.roles.cache.has(grarole.id) || member.roles.cache.has(botrole.id);
}``

Comment: Didn't work. Still counts everyone that voted, not only members with role

Answer (score 0):

This is very late, but try:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return (
        ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) &&
        (message.guild.member(user).roles.cache.has(grarole.id) ||
        message.guild.member(user).roles.cache.has(botrole.id))
      );
    };
```